# Do an aggregate with a populate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm having troubles with the following. I wonder if it's possible to do it with a single query.

So I have the following model :

```
const Analytics = new Schema({
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
  },
  loginTrack: [
    {
      user_id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Users',
      }
    }
  ]
}, { collection: 'analytics' });
```

And the user model :

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    nickname: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    instance: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Instances',
      default: null
    }}, {collection: 'users'});
```

I want to get the connected users for a specific instance at a specific date.

```
AnalyticsModel.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      createdAt: { "$gte": moment(args.startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'), "$lt": moment(args.endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      users: { $size: "$loginTrack" },
      "createdAt": 1,
      "_id": 0
    }
  }, {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$createdAt",
      "count": { "$sum": "$users" }
    }
  }
```

This gets me

```
[ { _id: '2019-02-11', count: 3 },
  { _id: '2019-02-08', count: 6 },
  { _id: '2019-02-07', count: 19 },
  { _id: '2019-02-06', count: 16 } ]
```

The results expected will be the same but I want to filter on users that belongs to a specific instance

Is it possible to do it with a single query or I need to do a populate first before the aggregation ?

**UPDATE**

I did some progress on it, I needed to add a lookup and I think it's ok :

```
   AnalyticsModel.aggregate([
  {"$unwind": "$loginTrack"},
  {
    $lookup:
    {
      from: 'users',
      localField:'loginTrack.user_id',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: '_users'
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      createdAt: { "$gte": new Date(args.startDate), "$lt": new Date(args.endDate)}
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _users: {
        $filter: {
          input: '$_users',
          as: 'item',
          cond: {
            $and: [
              { $eq: ["$$item.instance", new ObjectId(args.instance_id)] }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "createdAt": 1,
      "_id": 0

    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$createdAt",
      "count": { "$sum": { "$size": "$_users" } }
    }
  }
```

Also the dates were in string in the model.

The output is now :

```
[ { _id: 2019-02-11T00:00:00.000Z, count: 2 } ]
```

Comment: Could you show what output do you expect

Comment: Same output, expect that the results will be filtered according to users that belongs to a specific instance

Comment: So basically you want to join `user_id` inside `loginTrack` with user?